# way to search for key values inside a tupple like string column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, jpa-2.0

I need to save in one of **MySQL** database column named "properties" , a string the represents like 7 element tupple of a cpu  properties, for example :

**tupple** : TotalRam,NumOfcores,OsImage,IsHyperThreaded

**the actual string** : 200,3,LinuxSET EC Image SLES11SP4-4 Revision 0 ia32e,true

than I need to be able to do queries like : return all rows which -
NumOfCores==2 && isHyperThread==true

Im working with **curdrepository** inside spring boot context. the database is MySql but version that doesnt have **JSON**  data type .

What would be the best way to save , and query this kind of tupple/string ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must split the STRING. Here are the samples for your 4 Argument

```
-- TotalRam
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('200,3,LinuxSET EC Image SLES11SP4-4 Revision 0 ia32e,true',',',1);

-- NumOfcores
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('200,3,LinuxSET EC Image SLES11SP4-4 Revision 0 ia32e,true',',',2),',',-1);

-- OsImage
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('200,3,LinuxSET EC Image SLES11SP4-4 Revision 0 ia32e,true',',',3),',',-1);

-- IsHyperThreaded
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('200,3,LinuxSET EC Image SLES11SP4-4 Revision 0 ia32e,true',',',-1);
```

so your query is something lkke this:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(properties,',',2),',',-1) = 2
AND
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(properties,',',-1) = 'true';
```

You also can use VIRTUAL FIELDS. I will add a Sample in a few minutes.

Comment: SUBSTRING_INDEX function isn't available in jpa, I need to it in spring boot context :/

Comment: Build a View  and access this via Spring boot